# My css are loaded from minified file but not my function

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a webpage and I have an issue, I've created a `css` function for my image

```
#my_linkedin {
  background: url("../img/linkedin.png");
}
```

but my isssue is that when I'm calling the class in my `HTML`, the image doesn't appear.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto text-center mb-5 mb-lg-0">
    <a onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;" class="my_linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_self"></a>
</div>
```

My file is called `creative.css` and I also have the same file but minified. The issue is that on the webpage, the css are coming from the minified file, so how can I import my `css` who's coming from the `creative.css`please ? Because I don't want to have to put it in the minified one.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps change the selector in the CSS from `#my_linkedin` to `.my_linkedin` as you are using a class not an id on the element.

Comment: Apart from the incorrect selector, an `a` tag with no content will also have zero width and height. If that is the only CSS that you are applying to the tag then it will be invisible.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can have 2 problems.

First - link just empty and it width and height are equals to 0. So you cant see you backdround.

Second - I can see that you are using `#my_linkedin` as a selector which means that you is searching by id, replace to `.my_linkedin`.

Comment: Thx for the explanation, but I have another issue, I had a `height` and `width` but I still don't have anything loaded. And when I check the line in the element inspector, I don't have my class in the right column.

Answer (score 0):

You want `.my_linkedin { ... }`. `#` is for writing styles to match elements with matching `id="..."` attributes. `.` is for classes.

Comment: I have an issue, even if I change my class, I still don't have anything loaded in the page. When I check the element inspector, I have the line written, but in the css part in the right column, I don't have my class where I've import the image.

Answer (score 0):

Some errors here.

1. You are referring to a css rule, not function.
2. You are defining a css rule for a specific id, but on your html your element don't have an id, instead it have a class.

```
#someid {
     color: red;
}

.someclass {
    color: green
}
```

```
<p class="someid">BLACK</p>
<p class="someclass">GREEN</p>
<p id="someid">RED</p>
<p id="someclass">BLACK</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't related to whether or not the file is minified. Your selector applies to an element with `id="my_linkedin`, but your HTML doesn't have such an element. You can either change `class="my_linkedin` to `id="my_linkedin"` or you can change the CSS selector to read `.my_linkedin`

In CSS you don't call that a function. The `#my_linked` part is called a **selector** and the stuff inside the curly braces are called **properties**. Likewise, you can't *call* anything in CSS as you would in a programming language.

Comment: Yes thanks for this, but even if I change my fault and add a `height` and `width` to my background, it didn't load the image.

Comment: @Thomas_Vcheck an anchor (link) is an inline element. `height` and `width` have no meaning for inline elements. Test it by changing colors. Use your browser's Developer Tools to confirm that the CSS is affecting the element.

Comment: it's not, when I check the element inspector, I see the line but it didn't appear in the style section in the righty column